Why the first call to ::create() method will not set the id field on the model in Laravel?
I use Laravel 5.5 and October CMS 1.0 with MySQL 5.6 database and PHP 7.4.
I have several models with integer autoincrement id keys.
The model's default settings are left intact—I didn't change any of the key-related options.
I am able to reproduce the issue with the simplest possible model—with the int $id and string $test properties only.
What happens:
When I call a method from a Twig template to my controller, the first call to ::create will return a model with $id set to 0.
Both entries are created in the database.
After that, each call to ::create() will return a model with the $id adequately set.
I've spent some time researching this on the internet, and the only issue related to mine was connected to a Telescope, which I'm not using.
The database fields have the primary key defined.
As I mentioned, only the first call fails. Each subsequent call will work just fine.
My current workaround for the issue was to create a dummy table where I created entries before continuing with the function's logic.
It's stupid, but it allows me to continue before figuring out the issue.
I'm not sure where to start looking.
The worst part is that this issue does not affect my seeders. There, the models receive the $id just fine right after the first create is called.
Any ideas are welcome.
The code I used for testing:
Database table:
create table if not exists ${your_prefix_}test_table
(
    id           int unsigned auto_increment primary key,
    name          varchar(64)      not null,
    created_at   timestamp        null,
    updated_at   timestamp        null
) collate = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

Twig:
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="container">
        {{
            form_open({
                'data-request': __SELF__ ~ "::onTestModel",
                'data-request-success': 'testUpdate(data)'
              })
        }}
        <div class="row">
            {{ form_input( 'text', 'test_input', '') }}
        </div>
        <div class="row ">
            <div>First ID: <span id="first_id"></span></div><div style="margin-left: 1rem">Second ID: <span id="second_id"></span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-around mt-5">
            <div>
                {{ form_button ('Annuler', {'data-dismiss':'modal', 'class': 'btn btn-secondary'} ) }}
            </div>
            <div>
                {{ form_submit ('Suite ...', {'class': 'btn btn-primary' } )}}
            </div>
        </div>
        {{ form_close() }}
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function testUpdate(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $('#first_id').text(data.first_id);
        $('#second_id').text(data.second_id);
    }
</script>

Function in controller:
public function onTestModel() {
    $data = input();
    $model1 = TestModel::create([
        'name' => $data['test_input']
    ]);
    $model2 = TestModel::create([
        'name' => $data['test_input']
    ]);

    return ["first_id" => $model1->id, "second_id" => $model2->id];
}

Model:
<?php


/**
 *
 * @mixin \October\Rain\Database\Model
 * @property int $id
 * @property string $name
 * @method static \October\Rain\Database\Collection|static[] all($columns = ['*'])
 * @method static \October\Rain\Database\Collection|static[] get($columns = ['*'])
 * @method static \October\Rain\Database\Builder|FormationsDuoTypes newModelQuery()
 * @method static \October\Rain\Database\Builder|FormationsDuoTypes newQuery()
 * @method static \October\Rain\Database\Builder|FormationsDuoTypes query()
 * @mixin \Eloquent
 * @noinspection PhpFullyQualifiedNameUsageInspection
 * @noinspection PhpUnnecessaryFullyQualifiedNameInspection
 */
class TestModel extends Model
{
    use \October\Rain\Database\Traits\Validation;

    /**
     * The connection associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $connection = 'inx';

    /**
     * @var string The database table used by the model.
     */
    public $table = 'test_table';

    /**
     * @var array Validation rules for attributes
     */
    public $rules = [
        'name' => 'required',
    ];

}


Create your table with NOT NULL primary key constraint
create table if not exists inx_test_table
(
    id int unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment primary key,
    ...
)

And add $fillable in your model
protected $fillable = [
    'name'
];


Primary keys are not null by default. Why would adding $fillable change anything? It's unrelated to the issue, and its purpose is for something completely different. And obviously, adding it changes nothing.
